# Rename azure blob file and Download it

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have few files in azure blobs that are stored with unique file names and when the client wants to download, i want to rename to a friendly name.

I'm still using 2014 azure storage dlls in my project and i'm not planning to update them anytime soon. So i can't use built-in `ContentDeposition` and rename it.

I tried using following code in my controller:

```
        var blob = blobStorage.GetBlobRef("https://mysite.blob.core.windows.net/my-container/WERF3234435FFF_ERFas23E.doc");

        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
        blob.DownloadToStream(memStream);
        Response.ContentType = blob.Properties.ContentType;
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment; filename=abcd_New.doc");
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", blob.Properties.Length.ToString());
        Response.BinaryWrite(memStream.ToArray());
```

but its not downloading the file.

I also tried using this:

```
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
        blob.DownloadToStream(memStream);
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = blob.Properties.ContentType;
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment; filename=" + friendlyName.doc);
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", blob.Properties.Length.ToString());
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(memStream.ToArray());
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

I have my business logic in a separate solution and getting the blob reference from there to my main solution.

Am i missing something?

Comment: You have tagged this `asp.net-mvc` but I don't see any MVC here?

Answer (score 0):

When we're talking about ASP.NET MVC, I'm missing the Controller/Action in your code? You're not supposed to write to the `HttpContext` yourself when doing ASP.NET MVC. You have `ActionResult`s for that.

```
public ActionResult Download()
{
// ...
    var bytes = memStream.ToArray();
    return File(bytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, "abcd_New.doc");
}
```

The browser will decide whether to open the file download or open it directly within the browser window. If you want to control that, you will need the following piece of code before you call the `return File(...` method:

```
var contentDisposition = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
{
    FileName = "abcd_New.doc",
    Inline = false // true will try to open in Browser, false will download
};
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", contentDisposition.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You are right, i shouldn't use HttpContext in MVC. I tried setting the 'Inline' to false, still not downloading. Also if i set it to true its not opening the file either.

Answer (score 0):

We need to flush our response after wrote a file to response. I use the code which you provided. After adding following code, I can see the file can be download from server.

```
Response.BinaryWrite(memStream.ToArray());

Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```